# django order_by FieldError exception can not be catched

Tags: django, exception

```
from django.core.exceptions import FieldError

#This is a method of a class
def _order_item_list(self, item_list, order_items_by, previous_order_by):
    if order_items_by == previous_order_by:
        order_items_by = '-' + order_items_by 

    try:
        result = item_list.order_by(order_items_by)
    except FieldError:
        result = item_list

    return result, order_items_by
```

Now when I order by valid fields following the generated link,everything works perfect. When I edit a link and add some dummy fieldnames for ordering, it should be catched by this exception and the original list should be returned. But it is not happening, instead I  always get a FieldError from django.

FieldError at ...

Cannot resolve keyword u'fgsdffds' into field. Choices are: ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means there's a typo, or the exception happens elsewhere. Insert a debug line:

```
 import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

before the try-except and see how the code is executed. Try [PUDB](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb) or [IPDB](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb) debuggers instead of the standard one. Many questions disappear when you have a debugger and can see exactly what goes wrong.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The exception is raised later, it's surely because of django's optimizations to avoid many separate db operations... Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The reason the exception is not caught is because the `QuerySet` has not been evaluated yet.

To validate an arbitrary (user-specified) value used for a model field or `order_by` value, simply check to see if that model has a field by that name.

For example, say you have a model called `Ticket` and an arbitrary GET parameter called `field_name`. Here's how you might handle creating a valid `QuerySet` in `views.py`:

```
from django.db.models import FieldDoesNotExist
from myapp.models import Ticket

def index(request):
    default_field = 'id'
    field_name = request.GET.get('field_name', default_field)

    try:
        Ticket._meta.get_field_by_name(field_name)
    except FieldDoesNotExist:
        field_name = default_field

    tickets = Ticket.objects.all().order_by(field_name)
    return ...
```

Comment: descending order case will not work for this `-field_name`

Comment: In Django 1.10+ `get_field_by_name(name)` is deprecated. Use `get_field(name)` instead

Comment: The problem is if you order by descending order `'-field_name'` or by foreign key `'field__fkname'` you have to tweak the inputs. Is there another way to catch these as well?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and surely it was because the exception is later. In order to raise exception in try-catch block I modified the code in following manner:

```
try:
    result = item_list.order_by(order_items_by)
    **result = list(result)**
except FieldError:
    result = item_list
```

This worked for me.

Comment: This is a bad idea, as list() forces the evaluation of the QuerySet and loads it into memory. See my posted answer for a better solution.