# How can I validate if Django model has field given via GET parameter?

Tags: django

How can I validate if Django model has field given via GET parameter?

> FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'item_typea' into field. Choices are:
>   item_type, name, id...

```
order_by = self.request.GET.get('order_by', None) # item_typea
Item.objects.all().order_by(order_by)
```

Note that GET parameter can has value with minus sign (it's for sorting purposes), for example:

`-item_type` or `item_type`

Comment: there is an extra `a` after the item_type, how does it come?are you sending in the get like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply catch the exception:

```
order_by = self.request.GET.get('order_by', None)  # item_typea
try:
    queryset = Item.objects.order_by(order_by)
    # evaluate the queryset - that's when the exception will be thrown
except FieldError:
    # deal with error
```

Comment: it's weird but it doesn't catch this error and still got "FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173856/django-order-by-fielderror-exception-can-not-be-catched

Comment: @paul: You need to put the queryset evaluation into the `try` block. What you have above is just creating the queryset.

Answer (score 0):

You should just check:

```
order_by = self.request.GET.get('order_by', None)
if order_by:
    Item.objects.all().order_by(order_by)
```

Comment: That will catch a missing value, but not an invalid one (e.g. a string parameter that's not actually a field).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this using [get_field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_field):

```
from django.core.exceptions import FieldDoesNotExist


order_by = self.request.GET.get('order_by', 'id')
try:
    if order_by.startswith('-'):
        Item._meta.get_field(order_by[1:])
    else:
       Item._meta.get_field(order_by)
except FieldDoesNotExist:
    # field does not exist
```

FYI, this solution will not work with `foreignkey/m2m__field_name` expressions.